# QML: Accessing delegate Item within ListView by index

Tags: qml, qt5, qtquick2

I'd like to access an element (delegate) by index from the outside, which is part of a `ListView` by `index`.

In particular, I'd like to access the `text` property of a `TextInput` within the delegate.

Let's assume that model:

```
ListView {
    id: list
    model: ListModel {
        ListElement { label: "1st" }
        ListElement { label: "2nd" }
    }
    delegate: Item {
        Row {
            Rectangle {
                id: box
                Text {
                    id: _label
                    text: label
                    [..]
                TextInput {
                    id: _input
                    text: "enter something.."
```

`

I already figured out a property binding within the delegate that makes sense (`property alias input: _input.text`), since then I'd be able to access the input data from the `TextInput` via e.g. `list.currentItem.input`.

However I still struggle to access a particular delegate by `index`.

`list.model.get(i)` doesn't help, since apparently it accesses the model and not the delegate.

How can I access the text-property of the TextInput-widget by index - as in (pseudocode): `list.delegates.get(i).input`?

Comment: You could just add a string field to the model, and have the TextInput update that field.

Comment: I think you've made a typo in your code sample - delegate should be part of ListView, not of 'model'?

Comment: Looking to the code I probably see the point now. You are entering data inside a series of `TextInput`. Just don't use `ListView` for that!! A `Repeater` would suffice for such a purpose and you don't need to struggle with the issue you are talking about. `ListView` is NOT meant for this use case: delegates are generated on demand and thus  the text entered can be deleted/destoyed when the delegate goes out of the current viewport.

Comment: @VladimirPrus You're totally right - screwed that while cleaning up the code and making it a minimal test case. Fixed and thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo Thanks for you comment. However that means, I'm losing all the benefits of the ListView. Which means highlight, increment/decrement current item, scrolling, overshooting, even spacing doesn't seem available for the Repeater element. I know I didn't mention the need of those features in my initial posting, however I didn't know it will go that direction...

Comment: I take back the 'spacing' - I can easily do it within the column. But the initial question remains: How do I access specific elements within the `Repeater` and how can I navigate between the elements (as increment/decrement via cursor-keys within a ListView)?

Comment: Uhm, I've just written a small example that you can find [here](http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=0kff8B8S). Since you don't have indexes you can follow the first advice and use a custom index. That said, it really depends on the other requirements.

Comment: @BaCaRoZzo Thank you so much for your efforts!